# TYPO3 extension - f:uri.resource returns wrong path

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm writing a backend module for my own TYPO3 extension, where I'm wrapping the content into a `be.container` including a CSS and a JS file:

```
<f:be.container 
    includeCssFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'CSS/backend.css\')}'}" 
    includeJsFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'JS/backend.js\')}'}"
>
    <!-- module content -->
</f:be.container>
```

None of those resources gets included though. When I'm rendering `f:uri.resource` directly into the HTML, it - no matter which path - resolves to

```
/typo3/
```

which makes no sense to me. In my project, `/typo3/` is the path where the TYPO3 core is symlinked to, relative to my web path.

I've assured that my resource files are placed in `EXT:my_extension/Resources/Public/CSS/backend.css` and `EXT:my_extension/Resources/Public/JS/backend.js` respectively. I had a similiar issue including resources in the frontend, where it would resolve to just a `/` - in the end I decided to go with inclusion via Typoscript instead. I'm not sure if I'll be able to do this for the backend module as well. Any idea how to solve this? Maybe I missed something in the configuration which messes up path resolution for `f:uri.resource`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a minimal test case, try putting the plain output into your fluid template:

```
{f:uri.resource(path:'CSS/backend.css')}
```

If that yields the same result, it seems like the ViewHelper is not aware of the current extension. You can pass it the extension key as argument, see https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Uri/Resource.html.

Comment: Like I said, putting the path directly into the Fluid template only renders `/typo3/` for me. But adding the extension key actually renders the right path now! I don't use any custom ViewHelper, so I guess the default one is in use here. Any reason why it would not recognize the extension?

Comment: It might be an oversight in the backend context. Fluid is sometimes still a bit "rough" there. The extensionKey in the frontend is in the so-called `controllerContext` of `Controller`->`request`. Maybe that object is not completely filled in the backend.

Comment: I've printed out `getControllerExtensionKey` from the `request` object which returned `q_a`, although the extension key would actually be `qa`. Might this be the problem? Not sure where the underscore comes from, I assume the key derived from `$EM_CONF`, where I set the title to `Q&A`. I changed it to `QA` and reinstalled the extension, the key it prints out is still the same though.

Comment: Well, I just checked the naming conventions, and figured that `QA` being interpreted as camel case might be an issue in my extension as a whole... I'll rework the name and check if this resolves the issue.